# How to protect own software from copying

Tags: security

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you prevent the piracy of your software?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/10340/how-do-you-prevent-the-piracy-of-your-software)

Is possible to protect some file from copying if you are administrator of machine? I heard some story about some behavior: one software developer sells his software in some way. He is installing it on every client's computer and this software does not work on other computers or cannot be copied physically. How to implement the first and second protection. Is it effectively protection if software costs about $100 for all copies across client's company?